# Populate other field with value

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have a test many2one field. When it is populated I want the partner_id field to use the partner associated with that field. Following is not working:

```xml
<field name="partner_id" required="1"/>
<field name="x_test" context="{'partner_id': parent.partner_id}" />
```

Comment: Is the code in a wizard?

Answer (score 0):

you should try this :

```
<field name="x_test" context="{'default_partner_id': partner_id}" />
```

I don't know what you mean by `parent.partner_id` this works if you have a field named `parent` in the same view.

Comment: if you want x_text field to have the same partner_id in the view than you need to pass it as a default value for the form of the many2one

Answer (score 0):

i assume you wanna put same value of partner_id  in x_test field, then use related field

```
partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="partner")
x_test =  fields.Many2one('res.partner',related='partner_id', string="X Test")
```

in XML

```
<field name="partner_id" required="1"/>
 <field name="x_test" />
```